# NFC intermittent scan in bad signal areas

Tags: android, nfc

I have written an app that scans NFC tags. The app seems to work fine until the users go into a bad data strength area. I know this does not make sense but i can only forward my colleagues findings whilst out in the field.

There is nothing in my code that processes the NFC tag that interacts with the network. I understand the battery plays a part in the NFC capturing but this is not a problem as the app works fine in good signal areas.

I've tried looking on the net and wasn't surprised there is nothing on this subject.

Can anyone shed any light on this or has anyone had a similar problem.

thanks

[edit 1]
 These are the libraries i've integrated

```
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/core.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/ndeftools-1.2.3.jar')

compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.6@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Comment: it sounds like you have something in the app that requires the internet then

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I do use reflection to determine if the mobile data is switched on but that does not rely on making a web call and the code flows past this point successfully. I really have no ideas what this could be. I can't think of a reason NFC could be linked to signal stength

Comment: do you have any third party libraries which may be making network calls under the hood? Facebook, Google, Twitter, Firebase, etc?

Comment: @jgriffin to be honest i'm not sure as i'm the dev who has written the app but the customer that uses i've never met. it is a member of our sales team who has done a site visit in Morpeth northumberland. I can get more info of the phone and which apps are installed. would this cause an issue, what lines are you thinking along?

Comment: @jgriffin ah sorry i've re-read what you put about 3rd party libraries. yes i've integrated GCM (i use Firebase on another app i've done).

Comment: @jgriffin i've updated the post to show which libraries i've integrated